# Renaming files using .bat

Tags: batch-file, rename

I'm trying to to rename some files and I'm not getting anything to work.
The files are formatted like so:

```
AAA_STEST_BBBBBBBB.XML
```

and I need to rename them to:

```
BBBBBBBB_AAA.XML
```

Been trying to fish through the other threads but I can't piece together something that works.

Answer (score 0):

From the prompt,

```
for /f "tokens=1-4delims=_." %a in ('dir /b /a-d *_*_*.xml') do echo(ren "%a_%b_%c.%d" "%c_%a.%d"
```

Double each '%' if using within a batch file.

The rename commands are simply `echo`ed for checking. To activate the rename, remove the `echo(`